# HDMI port detected as DP

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, xrandr, hdmi

I have monitor in HDMI port, and the resolution is wrong. Should be 21:9 2560x1080, but isn't. Nvidia panel does not show the right resolution.

```
@:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1920x1080     60.15 +  40.06  
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

@:~$ lspci -v
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M] ( rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 053e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
        Memory at f5000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Answer (score 0):

Only switching to Nouveau drivers helped.

1. Install nouveau package, relevant to your distribution.
2. Disable blacklisting from "/usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf".
3. Add noveau drivers to xorg configuration.

Reference: [Missing 2560x1080 from Linux Nvidia Control Panel](https://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/missing-2560x1080-linux-nvidia-control-panel)